# Convert post permalink to real post id for live and stage site

Tags: wordpress, api

I am in a mesh and need some help.

There are three actor evolved.

1. Live Site / Production Site (wordpress)
2. Local Site / Stage / Testing Site (wordpress)
3. Third party analytic

**Background:**
I know its very bad but the fact is that the production sites and local sites content are not synced. i.e post id 1 in production can be as post id 24 in local.

**Problem Definition:**
I was assigned to use the third party's API to grab the list of top post with maximum hits and show it in our website.

```
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result_json = json_decode($result, true);
```

The above lines did that for me easily.

**Error:** 
Since the 3rd party did not had post excerpt, they send URL, image_link, hit_count, post title and author information as JSON.
So on my site I was able to show all these fields very well. But the problem started when my manager added post excerpt to the list. 
I tried converting URL to postid and got the post excerpt using:

```
get_the_excerpt(url_to_postid($top_posts['link']))
```

It worked for live site. but in the stage and local its not working. 
Well post URL has its domain name. Even when I replaced the domain name with my local or stage domain. its not showing any thing. and for some post when it shows the excerpt its not from the same article.
Guys need some idea.

Is there some way that I can get slug from URL? 
I tried using explode() function. But sometime the slug is not the last item in array.

Thank you for reading it all. I appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I came with a solution. Primarily Using the URL to get post ID, if not found using post title to get the post id.

```
public static function get_excerpt ( $id = null ) {
        $post = get_post($id);

        if ( empty($post) ) {
            return '';
        }

        if ( strlen($post->post_excerpt) ) {
            // Use the excerpt
            $excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;

            $excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $excerpt);
        } else {
            // Make excerpt
            $content = $post->post_content;

            $content = strip_shortcodes($content);

            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
            $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

            $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
            $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]');
            $excerpt = wp_trim_words($content, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more);

            $excerpt = wpautop($excerpt);
        }

        return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $excerpt);
    }
```

Called this function to get the excerpt.

```
$postid     = url_to_postid($top_posts['link']); 
$postid  = $postid!=0 ? $postid :  get_page_by_title($post_title, OBJECT, 'post')->ID; 
$excerpt    = self::get_excerpt($postid);
```

This worked in my case as I didn't have posts with same title.

I am still waiting for some better solution to my problem.